# Detect non-digitized university degree's authenticity by Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn

How can we detect by the look and feel of **non-digitized** university certificates’ authenticity through machine learning?

I am working in this project right now, where I have to detect the authenticity of non-digitized university certificate, I know how can we do it with a digital certificate.

The main problem here is that I don't have the dataset. I am thinking to follow the following approaches:

1. Extract the embossed seal on degree certificate and compare with the real one.
2. Extract the signature and feed it into forgery detection neural network.
3. Watermark detection.

Anyone can suggest me any other approach then that would be very helpful. TIA.

[image]

Comment: You should add more info about what you are trying to do. Even a picture of the certificate could be useful.

Comment: sure, I have some sample certificates. I am trying to detect the genuineness of degree certificate. If someone is using fake degree certificate at the time of job interview. Then, how to detect it beforehand?

Comment: what does *non-digitized* mean? You don't have digital pictures of it?

Comment: In India most university issues, offline certificates, which is not digital.

Comment: in which format? PNG, PDF, JPEG?

Comment: A mixture of JPG and PDF. I have some samples in PDF format, some are in JPG format.

Comment: I am working with scanned copies of the images, not the original one.